# Remotely control a remote Ubuntu server

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

We have a remote Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS server with SSH, which we use for Selenium tests. I have to login to https://mail.live.com/ from the server's IP address, and confirm the verification code in my email or phone, which I can't do with Selenium (Microsoft doesn't let me login from this IP until I confirm the code). How can I connect to the server with graphic user interface and use Firefox or Chrome? I tried a text browser but it doesn't support JavaScript, which is required.

My local computer is running Windows (10).

Comment: You should have an rdp client installed by default, it also supports connecting via ssh, as long as your server has a gui, you can login that way, open a browser, confirm the IP address.

Comment: @mondjunge I didn't understand how to login.

Comment: Click new connection, select ssh, enter IP Address of server, username and password (or select keyfile) and click connect? What exactly is your problem/what do you not understand?

Comment: @mondjunge How can I open a browser after I login with SSH?

Comment: Please forget my comments, when your local computer is Windows, I am not knowing how these work.

Comment: Basically what you need is a running gui on your server and an rdp programm for windows that supports ssh. Standard ssh terminal client will not give you a graphical frontend, that is needed for any graphical browser. If you can connect to your server via ssh, try to figure out how to start the gui on your server (i.e. sudo service lightdm start) and work with it

Answer (score 1):

If you have ssh server on remote host, just connect from a local ubuntu (or any **X running host**) using ssh and X-forwarding option.

from local

```
 ssh -X -l user remote
 remote$ firefox
```

where

- `remote$` is the prompt
- just run `firefox`, it sould appear on local windows.

EDIT:

To use remote display you need what is called an X server.

This can be

- Ubuntu with graphical session (no command line)
- Any flavour of unix, with X-window system
- Windows with Xming
- Note that using virtual host (like virtual box or vmware) can give you an X-window based host on window, this might be costly (install a linux just to get a display).

Simply running putty won't help.

Comment: I'm sorry, it didn't work. We didn't see Firefox on our local windows.

Comment: what is $DISPLAY's value ? does it point to local station (ideally, it should be 192.168.1.X:0, replace by IP of your local station)

Comment: I used a friend's computer with Ubuntu but he is busy and I can't use it again. I have a computer with Windows.

Comment: I installed Xming but how do I use it?